# Ruby on Rails: How to select all Cities which have at least 1 company and company category == 14

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to select all Cities which have at least 1 company and company category == 14.

```
City.includes(:companies).where('companies.category_id' => @category.id)
```

Associations

```
City    
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories   
has_and_belongs_to_many :companies 

Company   
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories   
has_and_belongs_to_many :cities 

Category   

has_and_belongs_to_many :companies   
has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implemented all associations as convention [suggests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) and you have these tables: `cities_companies` and `categories_companies` than
you can do it with this query:

```rb
City.distinct.joins(companies: :categories).where(categories: { id: @category.id })
```